# What you would see in a wormhole?

Tags: general-relativity, wormhole

Science fiction seems to depict the experience of traveling through wormholes (if possible of course) as seeing psychedelic colors or lines of light where stars once were (ie. 2001 or Contact). I wonder if theorists have any idea of what, if anything, the traveler would see.
This question may be subjective, but I know that there are theories about what an observer would see if traveling near the speed of light.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Around the worm hole would be a region with an intense gravitational field, and there would be gravitational lensing occurring, similar to that around a black hole. The difference would be that light that has passed through the worm hole would would be visible. So, a distorted view of the "other side" could be seen.

This [physicsbuzz article](http://physicsbuzz.physicscentral.com/2014/11/what-does-journey-through-wormhole.html) has some images and discussion. Note that the wormhole would be a spherical region in space, and not a 2d "stargate"