# Existence of wormholes and exotic matter

Tags: general-relativity, wormhole

Is it really possible for bending of space time to travel to another distant place in universe. Wormhole has two mouths which one is a black hole and another is a white hole which could let us out. Which is commonly called as Einstein-Rosen bridge, is there any pictorial proof of wormholes other than the theoretical proof by Einstein. Is there a possibility of having exotic matter which helps the wormhole to keep open up always??

Comment: What do you mean by "pictorial proof"?  The proof is mathematical: there is a "bridge" solution to the equations.  A picture would not be a "proof".

Comment: @JamesK not quite a dupe, as that question was about the *dimensionality* of wormholes whereas this asks about whether wormhole travel is possible, whether there's any observational evidence of them and how exotic matter might relate to them. An opportunity perhaps for a canonical answer on wormholes?

Comment: Related questions: [What is a wormhole?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/158) (has an excellent generalist answer), and [What you would see in a wormhole?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/12586) (answer includes a link to further discussion).

Comment: @Chappo yes whether there is any observational evidence of any wormholes